# What linux user does a nodejs subprocess run as?

Tags: node.js, docker, subprocess, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run a docker image using `docker run <imageName>` as a nodeJS subprocess but I am getting the error:

```
error:docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm trying to find out what user the subprocess or command is being run as using nodeJS `spawn`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign permission to current user to access docker image.

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error after adding the subprocess user to the group. I checked the user by running `whoami` as a subprocess.